# Hiding HTML Form or Converting to PHP

Tags: php, html

Currently we have 2 portals that our customers log into. I am trying to consolidate this to one. I want to make it when a customer logs in to our primary portal they can click another button and it automatically log them into the other system. I have created a form like below where the username and password is populated from the db. This works great the only issue is it is obviously not secure since you can see html in the source code. How can I either completely hide the below or how would I do this in PHP instead of HTML?

```
<html>
<form method="post" action="https://somesite.com/login.php">
    <p><input type="hidden" name="username" id="user_login" value="<?echo "$username"?>" /></p>


    <p><input type="hidden" name="password" id="user_pass" value="<?echo "$password"?>" /></p>

<fieldset class="bottom">
    <p><input type="submit" value="Log In" name="cdLogin" id="wp-submit" /></p>
<input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="" />
<input name="action" value="1" type="hidden" />

</fieldset>
```

Comment: "it is obviously not secure since you can see html in the source code" - Wrong.  It's not secure because *you have the password in the first place*.  You shouldn't have the user's plain text password.

Comment: You should NOT prepopulate the password in cleartext!! From a security point of view, that is really bad practice. If the browser caches the page, a third person might be able to recover the password for example. You should rather deliver a hash of the password and compare this hash on the other site.

Comment: Don't you just want this to submit once it is loaded? That can be done with javascript and would eliminate viewing the html.

Comment: Either way, what you're looking to do is create a Single Sign-On (SSO) for your PHP sites.  I don't have any direct experience with this, but Google can help you.  The approach you're taking here is incorrect, but there are others you can take.

Comment: @kwelch: No, it would not eliminate viewing the HTML.  Even if the form is immediately submitted, the core problem is that the password was delivered to the client in plain text.  They can see it any time they want.

Comment: @David's point is so damn right. It's IRRESPONSIBLE to save the user's password in cleartext in the database at all. You should NEVER do that, it's one of the most basic safety measures for websites. Just imagine your database is hacked and there are MANY users using one password for many different services...

Comment: OK guys dont freak out. The password and username is universal for all users this is a backend system. None of the users know there username/password for second portal. Secondly Im not about to put this into production. Im ultimately trying to figure out the best way of going about accomplishing this the right way. Prob going to be using cURL. Does anyone know how I would convert this to curl?

Answer (score 0):

Store username and password in the PHP session. As soon as the user clicks the second button use php curl to submit a post request.
A very good article about doing a post with curl can be found here http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl

Answer (score 0):

You can start a session and store both of those into session variables. Remember to unset the session after you are done with it. Just do a Google search for PHP Sessions
.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you didn't understood log in metod. I will explain my point:
When user is registering, when php insert user data in DB , make 1 more row. name it access_key or whatever u whant. That row means an encrypted unique key for every user.
Imputs > Check if data is corect in DB > as result (if user is conected) your php make a sesion and save user key in browser.
When protected page is loading, PHP check if that key stored in sesion is good, and gives acces to that page.
Good Luck!